# I feel as if I have been doing something. Correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

> I feel as if I were/was unloading a truck.
>
> I feel as if I've been unloading a truck.

Which is more appropriate and correct? It seems they are both good and tell about the present but the former is in the subjunctive mood.

Comment: The second sounds more natural to me.

Comment: Both are correct grammatically, but idiomatically I'd probably use "I feel like I've been unloading a truck" rather than either.